# Apex Programming: Calculate weeks difference between the two dates?

Tags: apex

How we can calculate weeks between two dates? I dont see any API. Does any API exsists? How we can do that?

I see there is an API to calculate Months only

```
Date myDate1 = Date.newInstance(2015, 2, 17);
Date myDate2 = Date.newInstance(2017, 12, 17);
System.debug('Months Between Two :'+myDate1.monthsBetween(myDate2));
System.debug('Weeks Between Two :'+myDate1.weeksBetween(myDate2));
```

The below line will never works. Any pointers to get weeks difference ?

```
System.debug('Months Between Two :'+myDate1.weeksBetween(myDate2));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no method called weeksbetween. You should leverage daysbetween and divide by 7

```
Date myDate1 = Date.newInstance(2015, 2, 17);
Date myDate2 = Date.newInstance(2017, 12, 17);
System.debug('Months Between Two :'+myDate1.monthsBetween(myDate2));
System.debug('Weeks Between Two :'+myDate1.daysBetween(myDate2)/7);
```

Comment: @Satrath - Thanx. This is good workaround. I like it. Apex yet to be matured like Java.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method in [Date Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm), you can do `myDate1.daysBetween(myDate2) / 7;`